# Regex to match vBulletin and myBB/IPB hashes

Tags: c#, regex, hash

I'm working on parsing a massive database with vBulletin and myBB/IPB hashes. I'm trying to figure out the regex to match these hashes.

Here's some examples of the hashes I'm trying to match.

IPB/myBB:

```
6445723fa554259ff5f7d4f3ac4beac3:]6poc
```

vBulletin:

```
297b9c3c749c211e5cc0995719ba31b8:[^I7`/@e>de*uE*ggUUD}Em,a!OHZ6
06f6d04af34479011ed48f9bd1fa67cd:BsK
```

I tried using this regex to match the vBulletin, but it didn't work:

```
([0-9a-zA-Z]{32}):(S{3,32})
```

How can I achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: (S{3,32}) means (Capture) 3 -32 literal S chars, you mean \S{3,32} I assume (3-32 non-whitespace chars)

Comment: ([0-9a-fA-F]{32}):(\S{3,32})

Comment: @tolanj that didn't work either.

Comment: How do your strings look in c#, remember \ is a c# escape as well.  Regex.Match("297b9c3c749c211e5cc0995719ba31b8:[^I7`/@e>de*uE*ggUUD}Em,a!OHZ6",@"([0-9a-fA-F]{32}):(\S{3,32})") matches, notice the @"" in the regex

Comment: @tolanj Just double checked and it actually does work. I was accidentally using .split(':') to check for salted/non-salted hashes in the database, and it was removing the ':' for every salted hash. Thanks to both of you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

`(S{3,32})` means (Capture) 3-32 literal `S` chars, you mean `\S{3,32}` (3-32 non-whitespace chars)